# Dumping Microsoft SQL database to file using command line

Tags: php, sql-server

I am attempting to dumping a Microsoft SQL (MSSQL) database to a file similar to how i would dump from a  MySQL database using php:

```
$cmd = "mysql --user=".$db_user." --password=".$db_password." --host=".$hostname." --database=".$database." --execute='SELECT * FROM ".$database." '> file.txt";
exec($cmd);
```

But i am trying to figure out the similarities in the command line as to how it is done above with **MySQL**
What is the proper command line syntax to execute this?
Thanks.

Comment: There's `sqlcmd`: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3654176/SQL-Server-2005-Command-Line-Tool-147SQLCMD148-150-Part-I.htm

Comment: That was just an example code, i don't want to limit it actually. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to write and test your [BACKUP command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) in TSQL. Second, you need to execute it, either using [sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) (Windows only) or by connecting directly to the database with whatever MSSQL drivers you use in PHP.

Since the SQL Server documentation is very complete and has numerous examples, you should be able to write the commands yourself. If you still have problems, please post what you have tried so far and exactly what you can't figure out.

Finally, you should always mention the version and edition of SQL Server, because it's often important to know when answering questions.